# MySQL - how to concat on load data statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this statement. Where i need the company field to be 'stackoverflow' instead of value from CSV.

uploaded csv

```
alice,bob,support@stackoverflow.com,+3233232,companyx,appointment
alice1,bob1,support1@stackoverflow.com,+3233232,companyy,appointment
```

SQL:

```
$sql = <<<eof
  LOAD DATA INFILE '$target_path'
   INTO TABLE sh_contact
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  (firstname,lastname,email,mobile,company,type)
eof;
```

**EDIT:**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$target_path'
INTO TABLE sh_contact
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(firstname, lastname, email, mobile, company, type)
SET company = 'stackoverflow', type='blabla';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable placeholder for the `company` column, and then manually overwrite the company to Stack Overflow:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$target_path'
INTO TABLE sh_contact
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(firstname, lastname, email, mobile, @var, type)
SET company = 'stackoverflow';
```

You might not even need to use `@var` in this case.  In any event, you don't need to know what the incoming value is, since you plan to just overwrite it.